# R Add elements to a list within list

Tags: r, for-loop

I am learning to some R programming. As an exercise I am trying to take a data frame, loop over the columns and assign each column name to a class in a list. Determining the column class can be done easily enough with:

```
data(diamonds)
lapply(diamonds, class)
```

but, instead of listing each column name and then it's class, I am wanting to try and create a list of column classes with each class containing a list of those column (i.e. variable) names. e.g.

Numeric.
variable1.
variable2.
variable3.

Factor.
variable1.
variable2.
etc

I get as far as the following but I can’t figure out how to group variables of the same class together. Any help would be appreciated:

```
data(diamonds)
type_list <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(diamonds)) {
    if (is.numeric(diamonds[[i]])) {
      type <- paste('Numeric')
      tmp <- names(diamonds[i])
      type_list[type][] <- tmp
      print(type_list[type][])
    } else if (is.factor(diamonds[[i]])) {
      type <- paste('Factor')
      tmp <- names(diamonds[i])
      type_list[type][] <- tmp
      print(type_list[type][])
    } else {
      print("Neither")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
unstack(stack(lapply(diamonds, class)), ind ~ values)

$factor
[1] "cut"     "color"   "clarity"

$integer
[1] "price"

$numeric
[1] "carat" "depth" "table" "x"     "y"     "z"    

$ordered
[1] "cut"     "color"   "clarity"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, `diamonds` dataset has columns with multiple classes (like `"ordered" "factor"`) I'll take `iris` as an example. You can use `split.default` to split names of the dataframe based on their class into separate lists.

```
split.default(names(iris), sapply(iris, class))

#$factor
#[1] "Species"

#$numeric
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `split` on the recoded `class`, standardize the `length`s of the `list` elements by padding `NA` at the end, and then `cbind` the `list` elements

```
lst1 <- with(stack(lapply(diamonds, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) 
      "Numeric" else if(is.factor(x)) "Factor")), 
             split(as.character(ind), values))
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
```

-output

```
    Factor Numeric
1     cut   carat
2   color   depth
3 clarity   table
4    <NA>   price
5    <NA>       x
6    <NA>       y
7    <NA>       z
```

---

Or if we don't need to recode, another option is

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
map(diamonds, compose(toString, class)) %>% 
    enframe %>% 
    unnest(value) %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(value)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name) %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  numeric `ordered, factor` integer
  <chr>   <chr>             <chr>  
1 carat   cut               price  
2 depth   color             <NA>   
3 table   clarity           <NA>   
4 x       <NA>              <NA>   
5 y       <NA>              <NA>   
6 z       <NA>              <NA>
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
reshape(transform(stack(lapply(diamonds, \(x) toString(class(x)))), 
    rn = ave(seq_along(values), values, FUN  = seq_along)), 
      direction = 'wide', idvar = 'rn', timevar = 'values')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_chr(diamonds, ~class(.x) %>% reduce(paste, sep = '_')) %>%
  {tibble(name = names(.), class = .) %>% group_split(class)} %>% 
  set_names(map(., ~unique(.$class))) %>% 
  map(~ `[[`(.,1))
#> $integer
#> [1] "price"
#> 
#> $numeric
#> [1] "carat" "depth" "table" "x"     "y"     "z"    
#> 
#> $ordered_factor
#> [1] "cut"     "color"   "clarity"

#alternatively we can create a list column with the values.

(class_dfs_list <- 
map_chr(diamonds, ~class(.x) %>% reduce(paste, sep = '_')) %>%
  {tibble(name = names(.), class = .) %>% group_split(class)} %>% 
  set_names(map(., ~unique(.$class))) %>% 
  map(~ `[`(.,1)) %>% 
  map(~ mutate(., values = map(name, ~diamonds[[.x]]))) )
#> $integer
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   name  values        
#>   <chr> <list>        
#> 1 price <int [53,940]>
#> 
#> $numeric
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   name  values        
#>   <chr> <list>        
#> 1 carat <dbl [53,940]>
#> 2 depth <dbl [53,940]>
#> 3 table <dbl [53,940]>
#> 4 x     <dbl [53,940]>
#> 5 y     <dbl [53,940]>
#> 6 z     <dbl [53,940]>
#> 
#> $ordered_factor
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   name    values        
#>   <chr>   <list>        
#> 1 cut     <ord [53,940]>
#> 2 color   <ord [53,940]>
#> 3 clarity <ord [53,940]>

#or stay with a column with no names

map_chr(diamonds, ~class(.x) %>% reduce(paste, sep = '_')) %>%
  {tibble(name = names(.), class = .) %>% group_split(class)}
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     name : character
#>     class: character
#>   >
#> >[3]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   name  class  
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 price integer
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   name  class  
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 carat numeric
#> 2 depth numeric
#> 3 table numeric
#> 4 x     numeric
#> 5 y     numeric
#> 6 z     numeric
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   name    class         
#>   <chr>   <chr>         
#> 1 cut     ordered_factor
#> 2 color   ordered_factor
#> 3 clarity ordered_factor
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>